# How to split xml file into files with correct file names?

Tags: python, grep, cat

I presently generate an **all.xml** (about 2GB) made of hundreds well formed svg files.

To simplify, I have something such :

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <metadata title="Cambodia"></metadata>
    <geodata WEST="102.1" NORTH="14.7" EAST="107.8" SOUTH="10.3"></geodata>
    <rect id="rectangle1" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="fill: purple;"></rect>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <metadata title="France"></metadata>
    <geodata WEST="-5" NORTH="51" EAST="10" SOUTH="41"></geodata>
    <rect id="rectangle1" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="fill: blue;"></rect>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <metadata title="Italy"></metadata>
    <geodata WEST="8" NORTH="46" EAST="18" SOUTH="35"></geodata>
    <rect id="rectangle1" x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80" style="fill: green;"></rect>
</svg>
...
```

I would like to get each svg element, its title, so I could print it to a file named according to `title`'s value, such `Cambodia-map.svg`, `France-map.svg` and `Italy-map.svg`.

**How to grep each svg from all.xml & its respective title's value ?**

It's then quite easy to print into files such :

```
$svg[i] > $title[i]-map.svg
```

Answer (score 2):

Using python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse('all.xml', events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'svg':
        title = elem.find('metadata').attrib['title']
        filename = '{}-map.svg'.format(title)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the XML using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module like this (I am assuming `data` to be the variable holding your XML. You would directly read from `all.xml` using `ET.parse()` ):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> for svg_ele in root.iter('svg'):
...     print svg_ele.find('metadata').get('title')
...
```

prints

```
Cambodia
France
Italy
```

Once you have this, it is easier to get the above info in a file:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> with open('output.dat', 'w') as out_file:
>>>     for svg_ele in root.iter('svg'):
...         line = svg_ele.find('metadata').get('title')
...         outfile.write('{}-map.svg'.format(line))
```

Comment: I think `output.dat` should be replaced by `all.xml`

Comment: @Hugolpz No. That is the output file. `all.xml` is the input file. In my code above, I am working with the snapshot of the `all.xml` OP used in his question. And I assume that it is stored as a string in `data`. I updated my answer to make that clear.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was confused to not see any `all.xml` as input.